# What is a good way to structure a timespan-oriented index?

Tags: data-structures, indexing

I'm finishing off work on a complex rule-engine for Hotel Rates with real-time queries. There is a lot of conditions addressing intersections of periods for options, restrictions and policies. All of these are per date, meaning the time of day is irrelevant.

It varies wildly, from customer to customer, whether period spans a few days or several years, so it is not a feasible solution to denormalize to each day in the period for each thing in the system.

Currently, I'm using skip lists with 2 entries per 'thing' that has a period. Then I can intersect 'things' starting before end of relevant period, and ending after the beginning of the relevant period. This works ok, it's the best compromise so far, but I still end up mostly allocating nodes I don't need, and spending CPU filtering away 'from' nodes that don't have a corresponding 'to' node in the output set.

It is implemented in C# (state is in-mem, loaded by event-streams)), mostly immutable objects, classes for things that gets passed around a lot, structs for private collections within classes.

Comment: I don't have time to write a full answer, but here's a pointer that may let you answer this yourself. There's a structure generally called a QuadTree that stores rectangles in a 2d space and let's you query it efficiently for a list of rectangles that intersect a rectangle you're interested in. There's also a 3d generalisation of the same structure called an Octree. What you're looking for is the 1-dimensional equivalent, which ought to be easy to work out looking at how the higher dimensional variants work.

Comment: Are you *sure* denormalizing per day is infeasible (have you measured)?  A few thousand entries ought to be trivial for a modern database, especially for something that changes relatively infrequently.

Comment: Just as a pointer: https://google.github.io/guava/releases/16.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/RangeMap.html (for Java and not C# but I imagine you can find an equivalent / implement your own).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_database

Comment: @KarlBielefeldt we measured testmigrations and timed systemtests agains 5 biggest customers. There is currently no databasase besides the eventstream (this is a readmodel, with the legacy system being the current commandmodel), Have postponed persistency dessisions yet, because we needed to grog a way to prevent the two thirds of possible combinations that is violation of some business rule. Some areas are graph-problems (negotiated rates, customers and companies), others like this one with the periods are 100000~300000 entries per month denormalized dates for periods of objects. 3 years is?

Comment: It would help if you edited to provide a thorough example.  On one hand you're talking about an index, which is usually done on slowly-changing data, and on the other hand you're talking about streams, which tend to be rapidly-changing and ephemeral.  We don't know your domain like you do.  Which parts change quickly and which are stable make a huge difference in this type of problem.

Comment: [Interval tree (Wikipedia.org)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) There are some other choices, all trying to optimize on similar situations.

Comment: @walpen the implementation you link to requires ranges to be disjoint (ie not overlapping). The current implementation as described in the question seems to suggest that the ranges in question can overlap, as otherwise the second half of the implementation could just be skipped and a simple Boolean test whether the last range start extends far enough could be used instead.

Comment: ... Although, you can pretty obviously convert a map of overlapping ranges to values into a map of non overlapping ranges to sets of values in O(n) time by having sorted lists of start and end points and stepping through both lists sequentially and tracking the set of active values at each point, so if slow updates are acceptable this could be a viable approach.

Comment: Thanks for the input everyone - I ended going with an interval-tree'ish implementation, taking the time to rebuild index on updates, and traversing overlapping nodes for child-nodes (inspired by quadtree). 
@Jules write an answer if you'd like the points :)